# Update table according to the another table value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Employees`

```
EmpID | EmpName | EmpDob
```

and `WareHouseEmployeers`

```
WarehouseEmpID | position | province
```

I need to update the `Employee` table according to the `WareHouseEmployers` table's values. How do I update the details about the employee table according to warehouse province and position?

I have tried this but it's not working:

```
UPDATE Employee
SET a.EmpName = 'Steven', a.EmpDob = '5-5-1990'
FROM Employee a, WareHouseEmployee b,
WHERE 
    a.EmpID = b.WareHouseEmpID 
    AND position = 'manager', province = 'central'
```

Can someone please help me to do that in SQL Server?

Comment: You need a join in your update - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Comment: U can use inner join to update the table
Please check my answer

Comment: Please check your table name `Employees`, In the given query the table name is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this script

```
UPDATE a
SET a.EmpName = 'Steven' , a.EmpDob='5-5-1990'
FROM Employee a 
INNER JOIN WareHouseEmployee b ON a.EmpID = b.WareHouseEmpID 
                               AND position = 'manager' 
                               AND province = 'central'
```

Comment: this also give erro: `a.EmpName and a.EmpDob` could not be found

Comment: its typo. Set Empployee to Employees

Comment: A good read about "UPDATE FROM"
"I guess that many people using UPDATE … FROM on a daily basis do so without being aware that they are violating all SQL standards."
LINK
http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2008/03/10/lets-deprecate-update-from.aspx

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma I for one do not agree with that article. And **every** major RDBMS violates SQL Standards in some way or form...